# Service binding

Tags: android, service

Есть такой код:

```
sConn = new ServiceConnection() {
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
                service = ((RestService.RestBinder) binder).getService();
                bound = true;
            }

            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                bound = false;
            }
        };   

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    bindService(intent, sConn, 0);
}
```

Если я вызову `service.someMethod()` сразу после `bindService();` получаю NPE, так как сервис не успел прибиндиться, и метод `onServiceConnected` не сработал, а мне `service.someMethod()` необходимо его вызвать при старте активити! Как быть? Какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: можно конечно сделать костыль и ожидать запуска сервиса. Но правильно - перенести нужную логику в onServiceConnected.

Comment: @KoVadim я попробовал, но onServiceConnected() срабатывает каждый раз когда активити вызывает onStart()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запускайте `ProgressDialog` сразу после старта и отключайте его при обработке `onServiceConnected`. Собственно с этого момента `service` будет доступен:

```
ProgressDialog pd;

sConn = new ServiceConnection() {
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
                service = ((RestService.RestBinder) binder).getService();
                bound = true;
                pd.dismiss();
                doSomethingWithService();
            }

            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                bound = false;
            }
        };

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pd.setTitle("Connecting to service...");
    pd.setMessage("Please wait.");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    pd.show();
    bindService(intent, sConn, 0);
}

void doSomethingWithService() {
  service.someMethod();
}
```

Ну и не забывайте проверять результат вызова `bindService`.